# Elegant way to create a list of random 0 and 1

Tags: python, random, list-comprehension

`model = [random.randint(0,1) if model.count(0) < 20 else 1 for _ in range(40)]`

Of course `model.count(0)` is wrong. 
Here we go for right code, but w/o list comprehension.

```
model = list()
for i in range(40):
   if model.count(0) < 20:
       model.append(random.randint(0,1))
   else:
       model.append(1)
```

I'm just love list comprehensions it makes me easier to work with NLP and massives. So it would be cool to find new features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*List Comprehension* are good, but they are not suitable for all the scenarios. In your case, writing an explicit `for` loop makes more sense.

However, you may use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) in order to get the similar result more efficiently. If you need both `0` and `1` to be 20 in count in the resultant list, you can do:

```
>>> import random
>>> my_list = [0]*20 + [1]*20

>>> random.shuffle(my_list)
>>> my_list
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

However if you want the count of `0` to be random between 0-20 (which your current code is doing), then you may modify the above logic a little like:

```
>>> zero_count = random.randint(0, 20)
>>> one_count = 40 - zero_count

>>> my_list = [0]*zero_count + [1]*one_count
>>> random.shuffle(my_list)
>>> my_list
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Cool, but I needed random number of zeroes in range(20) but with shuffle I always got 20 zeroes and 20 ones :)  So list must include from 0 to 20 zeroes and rest ones

Comment: Check the second code snippet which I added recently @DanielFedrain explaining the same scenario

Comment: thanks for support !